# Javascript How to use the facebook subscribe event for like button when it open in a new dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

When I click the facebook like button, I have a popup on the screen so I can't use the subscribe event bellow :

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(url, html_element) 
{
   // Action here
});
```

Do you know any alternative please ? I'm using this just to check if a user hase liked the page !

[image: capture]

Comment: why do you want to know if the user liked your page? what for exactly?

Comment: Just to authorize him to participate to an event

Comment: that´s not allowed anyway, that´s why i asked. it´s called "incentivizing", check out the platform policy. you are not allowed to gate content (or an event participation) behind a page like, and you are not allowed to reward users in any way for a page like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/

> edge.create and edge.remove JS SDK Events: These Events will no longer be accessible. As an alternative, you can use our Webhooks and be notified every time someone likes one of your Facebook Pages.

The only way to check if a user liked your Page is to authorize the user with the `user_likes` permission. Of course you have to go through review with the permission.

Comment: is there any javascript documentation to follow to ask users for user_likes permission? Thanks

Comment: if you don´t even have facebook login yet, this is where you need to start: https://developers.facebook.com/products/account-creation - but, as i commented in your question, your use case will not get you approved because it´s not allowed.